# Multiple drawings in p5 js

Tags: javascript, p5.js

```
 function setup(){

 createCanvas(500,500);

 }

 var pos1;
 var pos2;

 function draw() {
 background(244, 248, 252);

    text("X:" + mouseX/10,460,10);
    text("Y:" + mouseY/10,460,20);

   ellipse(pos1,pos2,5,5);
   fill(0);
   }

function mousePressed() {
pos1=mouseX;
pos2=mouseY;
 }
```

Every time when I press the mouse, the code generates a ellipse. However, I want to keep the old ellipse and generate a new one. How can I do it? For every time I press the mouse a new ellipse will generate, not deleting the old one.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options:

**Option 1:** Notice that the first line in your `draw()` function is a call to `background()`. This line clears out old frames. If you don't want to clear out old frames, then you could move the line into the `setup()` function instead.

**Option 2:** You could maintain an array of prior values, and draw them to the screen each frame.

**Option 3:** You could draw your circles to a buffer, then draw that buffer to the screen each frame. The `createGraphics()` function would come in handy here.

Comment: how the createGraphics() function would implement in this source code?